# Android EditText - show Toast after user finished editing

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-toast

I have an EditText in my android code and I want to show a Toast message after user stops editing the field.

```
    final EditText kurz = findViewById(R.id.kurz);

        kurz.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.saved_settings), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                if(s.length() != 0) {

String waketime = String.valueOf(kurz.getText());

                    getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("xxxx", waketime).apply();

                }

                else { kurz.setText("1");

                }

            }
        });
```

First I tried to add Toast to `onTextChanged` - logically this showed the Toast each time user changed anything in the field.

Then as you can see in my code I put Toast in `afterTextChanged`, but nothing changed. The message is showing each times the user types anything, so the message shows many times.

I want to show the Toast only once, after the user finished editing the field (the focus stays there, as this is the only field).

So something like if there is 5 sec pause after editing, it means probably user finished editing and show toast only in this case

Comment: Is there better way of determining user finished his input rather then 5 sec timeout?

Comment: are you asking me? :) I just came with that idea, not sure if there is some other solution how to do that. Practically I can use a timer, but timer creates new thread each time to run the task. E.g. if user insert 100 chars, timer starts 100 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to not follow this concept of waiting when you are dealing with multiple `EditTexts`. However since you explicitly stated that you only have one I would say your approach is fine.

Anyway to show your `Toast` after 5 seconds (maybe 2-3s would fit better) you basically do the following:

```
val handler = Handler()
val runnable = Runnable {
    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Woop Woop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
kurz.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000)
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }

})
```

What I am doing here is:

- Create a `Handler` and a `Runnable`
- In `afterTextChanged` `postDelay` that `Runnable` 5 seconds

Since `afterTextChanged` can be called many times, you have to make sure that already existing `postDelayed` `Runnables` are cancelled. You do this by calling `removeCallbacks` on the `Handler`.

*(Hope the Kotlin code is not an issue)*

**EDIT:** `Handler` and `Runnable` would look like this in Java:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Woop Woop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: well, just wanted to ask for that 'val' and now I see it's Kotlin :) not using this, but thanks for the Handler idea

Comment: I could rewrite it in Java if you want ;) Or ask me if you have difficulty understanding it. 

val just refers to a constant value.

Comment: val is same as final variable

Comment: Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable {Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.saved_settings), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();} but there is something wrong

Comment: method calls are the same (removeCallbacks / postDelayed) just a semicolon is missing at the end.

Comment: perfect! now it is working as I wanted. I set it for 2000ms, it's fine. Thank you!